# Android action bar item 's image slow down application

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-drawable

I noticed this, when i insert images on action bar slows down app.

To insert images into action bar items i use this, into my `menu.xml`:

```
[...]
<item
        android:id="@+id/foo"
        android:icon="@drawable/foo"
        android:showAsAction="always">
[...]
```

and then inside  my activity i do it:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

so how i can optimize the images taken directly from drawables resources?

thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the dimension of image in px

Comment: yes, i created this image with paint.net

Comment: so what its dimension example 144 by 144

Comment: _image should be smaller than 40dp tall and 30dp wide._

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal how i can modify my xml to accomplish this?